# Excluding specific VMs from Ansible Inventory: VMware

Tags: ansible, vmware, ansible-tower

I have configured a group with source "VMware vCenter" in Ansible Tower. As per the documentation, one can specify Source Variables to

> Override variables found in vmware.ini and used by the inventory
>   update script. For a detailed description of these variables view
>   vmware.ini in the [Ansible github repo](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/vmware.ini).

An excerpt from the GitHub file -

```
Specify a prefix filter. Any VMs with names beginning with this string will not be returned. 
prefix_filter = test_
```

In my case, I have at least three prefixes that need to be excluded. However, when I try to do that by specifying prefix_filter three times, only first one seems to work. How can I exclude VMs which start with names other than Te?

[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert with Tower, but with bare Ansible I'd try to use newer inventory script [vmware_inventory.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/vmware_inventory.py) with jinja `host_filters` or to patch vmware.py `if vm.name.startswith( prefix_filter )` to something that suits your needs.

Comment: I am trying to tweak the vmware.py to suit my needs. It is said that it relies on vmware.ini file but I don't see that ini file anywhere. Do you have any idea of which would be the right place to create one such file? Even vmware_inventory.py can rely on an ini file but there's no mention of where to find / create one.

Comment: First `VMWARE_INI` env var is checked for path, then it looks in the same directory as vmware.py

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov, we managed to tweak the prefix_filter in vmware.py to exclude the VMs. If you could post your first comment as an answer, I will accept it. We no longer use a ini file.

Comment: Cool, glad that it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from my comment:

I'd try to use newer inventory script [vmware_inventory.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/vmware_inventory.py) with jinja host_filters or to patch vmware.py `if vm.name.startswith( prefix_filter )` to something that suits your needs.